# Fourier Transform: why do all segments generate the same magnitude response?!

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm working on a DTMF program, and what I've done is to break the one long input signal I initially receive into a bunch of smaller components. I perform an FFT on each of the small components and then check the magnitude response of the specific bin component that I'm interested in. My question is, WHY ON EARTH is every segment no matter how small, of a component which contains a piece of, say, the signal for the number 1, (697 * 1209 Hz), look the same as all the other small components?!

Have I phrased that lucidly enough for general comprehension? If not, let me know & I'll try to be more explicit.

Comment: *look the same as all the other components for the signal of 1, in the example I gave above

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, you can simply edit your question. Let's start with basic questions: is the length of every segment the same? Moreover, is it of the type $2^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: I guess yes becasue it's fft, from jmathstudio, but in fact they are not, such as edge cases, so maybe they zero pad it as part of their function?

Comment: can you help me to tag this appropriately, i lack the reputation to properly categorize this inquiry!

Comment: Actually, you should be the one answering to that questions. What software are you using? Usually, they have an "help" section, a "function browser" or something like that. The first thing you should do is, in fact, check if there is automatic zero-padding or not. Verify it; it's a very simple first step. After that, remember to check the phase of the FFT, it may shed light on what's happening with your code.

Comment: I guess it must have the zero padding because how else would they take a 400 point fft on a sample of less than 400 points?

What I really want to know is, is the magnitude response always essentailly the same, no matter which part of the wave you sample from?

Comment: The answer to your last question is: it depends. Update the question with an analytical expression of your waveform (if you have it). If you don't have it, use at least an approximate expression. However, I do not really understand the problem: why can it not? Especially if the segments are of equal length and they essentially represent the same thing, which may happen, e.g., when the waveform is periodic and correctly sampled. Anyway, do a sanity-check on the phase.

Comment: But what I'm saying is I guess the phase doesn't matter it's a DTMF program that's written in Java, want me to send you the code?

Comment: They shouldn't be the same but should increase as the amount of energy at those given frequencies increase as you increase the duration of the signal. My guess is a bug in your code.

Comment: Exactly what *AnonSubmitter85* said: there may be a bug. A sanity-check on the phase usually reveals it (and the phase *does* matter, not for the goal of your specific application, but for general understanding of what's happening). However, care must be taken when saying "they shouldn't be the same": we are talking about N-sequences, of which we take the DFT (implemented by FFT). There are cases when the ESD (Energy Spectral Density) are exactly the same, e.g., take a sinusoidal waveform of period $T \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and take each segment of equal length $L = n T$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: All the segments obtained by the waveform above are (eventually) *phase-shifted* versions of the same N-sequence, with *exactly* the same energy, thus the same magnitude of the DFT. If you don't check the phase, they appear the same, since the magnitude is actually the same. Let me ask again: are the segments of equal length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int xx=0; xx < totalLength; xx+=400)
    {
        if(xx < totalLength - 400)
        {
            float[] c = Arrays.copyOfRange(dtmfSignal, xx, xx+205);

            CVector fft = FFT1D.fft(new Vector(c), 205);


            Vector mag = fft.getMagnitude();
```

So as you can see it's divided up into smaller components and then the relevent frequency bin is examined in order to determine a response above a certain threshold.

Would you, could you, please help me to understand exactly why it makes no different which one of the 205 sample segment, so long as it is sliced from the same cloth as a different part of the signal that is also composed of the similar two inputs, it will yield the same magnitude response, no matter which part of the wave it's come from.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code with a random signal of 1600 length and could get different magnitude for a particular frequency 'f'. 
Not sure why you get same magnitude response for all segment? Can you try removing mean from the signal before taking it's FFT use Vector d = new VectorStatistics().deMean(c);

Apart for this; check your code. Try plotting the magnitude response to check if they are indeed same or different. Do mag.plot("Frequency Response","mag");